# Can't retrieve the value of a text input with jquery

Tags: jquery

It kills me when something so simple ends with me banging my head against the for an hour.

I'm just trying to collect for information for ajax submission.

What I can do is retrieve attribute values and I can set the value of a text input and then retrieve that value but if the value was set by the user manually I cannot retrieve that value.  For testing purposes I added buttons that act out everything that I have tried.

I also have it set up on jsfiddle and it works fine there
http://jsfiddle.net/x6p5k/

I suspect the problem is somewhere in the pageslide jquery plugin I'm using
http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/

Thanks for the help

HTML

```
<label class="control-label" for="inputName">Name</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="inputName" name="inputName" value="" placeholder="Name">
  </div>

 <label class="control-label" for="inputEmain">Email</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" value="" placeholder="Email Address">

...

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="value">value</button>  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="type">type</button>    
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="set_value">set value</button>
```

jQuery

```
$("#value").click(function()
    {
    var Variablename = $("#inputName").val();
    window.alert(Variablename);
    });

$("#type").click(function()
    {
    var Variablename = $("#inputName").attr("type");
    window.alert(Variablename);
    });

$("#set_value").click(function()
    {
    $("input#inputName").val("hello world");
    });
```

The site I'm trying to get this to work on is http://whispersofawillow.org in a modal when you click on contact on the top menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fact that you are using 2 divs with same id :

```
$("input#inputName").length
```

check your console with the line above.

Every time you add the form to your page, a new input will be added to your page as I have investigated.

Comment: `$('#inputName').length` returns 1 .

Comment: if you open the form there are 2